como utilizar bootstrap en lugar de vite en laravel 10
Esto es mi código utilizando Laravel 10 en resources/views/layouts/app.blade.php quiero utilizar Bootstrap ya que no me carga vite al ejecutar la aplicación.
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- CSRF Token -->
    <meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">

    <title>{{ config('app.name', 'Laravel') }}</title>

    <!-- Fonts -->
    <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="//fonts.bunny.net">
    <link href="https://fonts.bunny.net/css?family=Nunito" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Scripts -->

     @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss','resources/js/app.js'])

</head>    


adentro de la pregunta, sigue diciendo vite.. creo que por eso nadie te contesto nada.. la pregunta estaba mal...

la solución fue eliminar la linea de codigo:  @vite(['resources/sass/app.scss','resources/js/app.js'])  luego instalar bootstrap en la aplicacion y agregar las siguientes lineas de codigo:  <script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script> <link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">

@amilcarjosimar haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio. Además de modificar tu pregunta para que sea más entendible, pon en la zona de respuestas qué ha respondido a tu pregunta. Luego, acepta tu respuesta.

si muchas gracias por los comentarios
